# How can I change the font style inside <md-button>

Tags: html, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm using AngularJS and Material Design and one thing that is bothering me is that I can't reproduce exactly the style that is used on google's oficial website for the button tags. 
[Material Deisgn Button Demo](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.button)

When I use a button like this:

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Start</md-button>
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary"><label>Start</label></md-button>
```

I get something like this:

[image: Button IMG]

and I was expecting to have something like this:

[image]

which is kinda the same code that I wrote according to the *source code* provided on their website

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Primary</md-button>
```

I have tried using `<b></b>` tags instead of the label but the result is similar, some letters doesn't fit very well... Is there something I am missing to fix this font issue?

Edit: Example of one of my codes.

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module("demoApp", [
      "ngMaterial",
      "app.config",
      "app.controller"
    ]);

})();
```

```css
.md-button {
  min-width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../material/angular-material.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="demoApp">
  <div layout="column" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
    <md-toolbar layout="row">
      <h1 class="Title">Ten plus ten is {{10+10}}!</h1>
    </md-toolbar>
  </div>
  <div layout="row">
    <div>
    </div>
    <div layout="column">
      <div layout="row">
        <div flex="25" flex-sm="0" flex-md="0"></div>
        <div flex class="md-whiteframe-z1" layout="column" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
          <md-toolbar class="md-primary">
            <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
              <span class="md-flex">Parameters</span>
            </div>
          </md-toolbar>
          <md-content class="md-padding">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne quod novum mei. Sea omnium invenire mediocrem at, in lobortis conclusionemque nam. Ne deleniti appetere reprimique pro, inani labitur disputationi te sed. At vix sale omnesque, id pro labitur reformidans accommodare,
              cum labores honestatis eu. Nec quem lucilius in, eam praesent reformidans no. Sed laudem aliquam ne.
            </p>
            <p>
              Facete delenit argumentum cum at. Pro rebum nostrum contentiones ad. Mel exerci tritani maiorum at, mea te audire phaedrum, mel et nibh aliquam. Malis causae equidem vel eu. Noster melius vis ea, duis alterum oporteat ea sea. Per cu vide munere fierent.
            </p>

            <div>
              <div layout="column" ng-controller="ParametersController as params">
                <md-content class="md-padding">
                  <div layout layout-sm="column">
                    <md-input-container flex>
                      <label>Parameter 1</label>
                      <input ng-model="params.param1" placeholder="placehold text">
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container flex>
                      <label>Parameter 2</label>
                      <input ng-model="params.param2" placeholder="placehold text">
                    </md-input-container>
                  </div>
                  <div layout layout-sm="column">
                    <md-input-container flex>
                      <label>Parameter 3</label>
                      <input ng-model="params.param3" placeholder="placehold text">
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container flex>
                      <label>Parameter 4</label>
                      <input ng-model="params.param4" placeholder="placehold text">
                    </md-input-container>
                  </div>
                </md-content>
              </div>

              <div layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                <div></div>
                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="sendParameters()">Primary</md-button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </md-content>
        </div>
        <div flex="25" flex-sm="0" flex-md="0"></div>
      </div>

      <div layout="row">
        <div flex="25" flex-sm="0" flex-md="0"></div>
        <div flex class="md-whiteframe-z1" layout="column" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
          <md-toolbar class="md-primary">
            <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
              <span class="md-flex">Algorithm</span>
            </div>
          </md-toolbar>
          <md-content class="md-padding">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne quod novum mei. Sea omnium invenire mediocrem at, in lobortis conclusionemque nam. Ne deleniti appetere reprimique pro, inani labitur disputationi te sed. At vix sale omnesque, id pro labitur reformidans accommodare,
              cum labores honestatis eu. Nec quem lucilius in, eam praesent reformidans no. Sed laudem aliquam ne.
            </p>
            <p>
              Facete delenit argumentum cum at. Pro rebum nostrum contentiones ad. Mel exerci tritani maiorum at, mea te audire phaedrum, mel et nibh aliquam. Malis causae equidem vel eu. Noster melius vis ea, duis alterum oporteat ea sea. Per cu vide munere fierent.
            </p>
          </md-content>
        </div>

        <div flex="25" flex-sm="0" flex-md="0"></div>
      </div>
      <div layout="row">
        <div flex="25" flex-sm="0" flex-md="0"></div>
        <div flex class="md-whiteframe-z1" layout="column" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
          <md-toolbar class="md-accent">
            <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
              <span class="md-flex">Video</span>
            </div>
          </md-toolbar>
          <md-content class="md-padding">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne quod novum mei. Sea omnium invenire mediocrem at, in lobortis conclusionemque nam. Ne deleniti appetere reprimique pro, inani labitur disputationi te sed. At vix sale omnesque, id pro labitur reformidans accommodare,
              cum labores honestatis eu. Nec quem lucilius in, eam praesent reformidans no. Sed laudem aliquam ne.
            </p>
            <p>
              Facete delenit argumentum cum at. Pro rebum nostrum contentiones ad. Mel exerci tritani maiorum at, mea te audire phaedrum, mel et nibh aliquam. Malis causae equidem vel eu. Noster melius vis ea, duis alterum oporteat ea sea. Per cu vide munere fierent.
            </p>

          </md-content>
        </div>
        <div flex="25" flex-sm="0" flex-md="0"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.7.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>

  <script src="app.module.js"></script>
  <script src="app.config.js"></script>
  <script src="app.contoller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: We'd need to see your code. You may have other styles cascading and  affecting the result.

Comment: Added the code to the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the demo page you have linked to, it also has some styling added onto the page outside of an external stylesheet.

This style reads:

```
.buttondemoBasicUsage section .md-button:not(.md-fab) {
    min-width: 10em;
}
```

As you can see it adds a min-width to the buttons as long as they aren't `.md-fab`.

Ultimately, you just need to add something to your CSS to set a `min-width` to the button elements.

Something basic like this:

```
.md-button {
    min-width: 10em;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm still trying to figure out how to change the font to the bold-looking one [Like this](http://i.imgur.com/BX5NJ41.png) (The top one is mine and the botton one is google's)

Comment: thank you! I didn't know about the font-weight property. My buttons are looking nice now!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, it was because I (stupidly) forgot to include the 'Roboto' font.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

You need to include something like this on the page, probably only need the 500 for the bold buttons.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you want to use. If you using in any list item then

```
<md-button layout-fill>Post Requirement</md-button>
```

or you can use

```
<md-button style="width:200px;">Post Requirement</md-button>
```